icmp echo reply not sent over wireguard tunnel
I just setup a Wireguard instance on an opnsense firewall with a public IP. I set this up by following the Opnsense Road Warrior Wireguard guide.
The issue that I am running into is that icmp echo replies aren't making their way back over the vpn tunnel from hosts on the LAN. In this scenario I have three comptuers. The firewall running opnsense with a LAN IP of 10.5.1.1. the server running Ubuntu with an IP of 10.5.1.10 and my computer connecting to the Wireguard VPN with a Wireguard IP of 10.5.20.3. When I ping'd the server from the firewall I was able to get ping responses to the server. But no such luck when pinging the server from my computer.
When I ran
tcpdump -i any "icmp"

on the server I saw that there was echo requests making it to the server from my computer but they weren't being replied to.
Server tcpdump:
18:33:41.417384 IP 10.5.20.3 > 10.5.1.10: ICMP echo request, id 49, seq 8, length 64
18:33:42.441373 IP 10.5.20.3 > 10.5.1.10: ICMP echo request, id 49, seq 9, length 64
18:33:43.465378 IP 10.5.20.3 > 10.5.1.10: ICMP echo request, id 49, seq 10, length 64
18:33:44.489358 IP 10.5.20.3 > 10.5.1.10: ICMP echo request, id 49, seq 11, length 64
18:33:45.513380 IP 10.5.20.3 > 10.5.1.10: ICMP echo request, id 49, seq 12, length 64

When running tcpdump on the firewall I got the same story when pinging the server from my computer.
Firewall tcpdump:
13:32:13.051964 IP 10.5.20.3 > 10.5.1.10: ICMP echo request, id 48, seq 1, length 64
13:32:14.076619 IP 10.5.20.3 > 10.5.1.10: ICMP echo request, id 48, seq 2, length 64
13:32:15.100579 IP 10.5.20.3 > 10.5.1.10: ICMP echo request, id 48, seq 3, length 64

I am new to complex networking but my thoughts was this was either a firewall issue or subnetting issue.
The Wireguard addresses are in the 10.5.20/24 subnet but in the documentation it explicitly states that I have to have the Wireguard subnet be totally unique. Hence why it is outside of my 10.5.1.1/20 LAN subnet.
For Firewalling I did every combination of firewall rules that allowed traffic In/Out between the VPN net and the LAN net. Each time I tested it it had the same result.
Then end goal is to have all traffic not just ICMP but any more troubleshooting ideas or a solution would be appreciated, thanks!

If the server is receiving ping requests, but not replying to them, check the firewall on the server itself -- probably it permits inbound access only from your LAN subnet (10.5.1.0/24); try running iptables-save and nft list ruleset as root to check.
